# Line breaks at the end of HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to replace html tags with the same html tag plus a line break:

```
content = content.replace(new RegExp('(</.*?>)', 'gi'), '$1 \n').replace(/\/>/g,'/> \n');
```

Here's what happens in my site:

I write some text. I copy the text. I paste into a div and the above is run which adds line breaks. I then copy this text out of the div. I then add more content, and repeat the process.

The problem is that a further line break is added to previous content when I perform a copy and paste again. So the second time I do the above, I get two line breaks, third time, three line breaks etc.

How can I make the above expression replace tags with tags and line breaks and ignore (or replace again) tags that already have line breaks.

Comment: Can you use jquery for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var content = "<Test>Test</Test><Test2>Test2</Test2><Test3 /><Test4>Test4</Test4>";
var regexTest = new RegExp('(</.*?>)(?!\\n.*)', 'gi');
var regexTest2 = new RegExp('/>(?!\\n.*)', 'g');
content = content.replace(regexTest, '$1\n').replace(regexTest2,'/>\n');
alert(content);
content = content.replace(regexTest, '$1\n').replace(regexTest2,'/>\n');
alert(content);
//remove linebreaks
content = content.replace(/\n/g, '');
alert(content);
```

This adds a negative lookahead `(?!...)` so it checks to make sure there isn't already a `\n`. If you get rid of the space between `$1` and `\n` and `/>` and `\n` then you don't need the `\\s` in the regex...

Comment: @panthro I updated the answer...If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the update almost there i think - just it neglects this: replace(/\/>/g,'/> \n');

Comment: To tackle self escaping tags.

Comment: @panthro alright updated it should work now...Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect - as a side question is there a way to stripe out the line breaks again (I wish to do this before it goes into a database)

Comment: @panthro you mean just get rid of the linebreaks? Because you could just replace all `\n` with `''`?

Comment: @panthro Also if this answer helped please accept it as the correct answer...Thanks!

Comment: Yeh when i'm done I want to get rid off all line breaks that the above code added in.

Comment: @panthro just do `.replace(/\n/g, '');`...I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've tested it but it doesnt work 100%. I remove the line breaks then add them back in again - it adds an extra space

Comment: @panthro that's because you had a space in your question. I told you in my answer if you didn't want the space just remove it...

Comment: @panthro there i just updated it again without the space.

Comment: @panthro from your question `'/> \n'` and `'$1 \n'` notice the space in both areas...